# How does one use "takeable=True" and indexers in dataframe.set_value , especially with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

The documentation for **pandas.DataFrame.set_value** describes the argument takeable thusly: takeable : "*interpret the index/col as indexers, default False*"

My specific current goal is to input some fairly widespread index and column lists into set_value to set specific areas all to certain values (ideally with expansion of the dataframe anywhere the columns don't exist). I'm also using a multi-index so it feels like I need a fairly good understanding of what exactly is meant by "indexers" here. I looked at the source but it didn't immediately seem self-evident what I should feed into the col and index values in this instance.

For example:

```
df.set_value((":",":"),(":",":"),0,takeable=True)
```

throws an error about valid indices (and if I remove the quotes I get syntax errors until I add them).

What I'd really like to do is:

```
df.set_value(complicated_indexer,complicated_column_indexer,0,takeable=True)
```

where I'd set up those indexers ahead of time and might be pointing at many different column/index lines.

Is that not what the phrase *interpret the index/col as indexers* means or is there some arrangement of .loc or pd.IndexSlice that can generate arbitrary indexers to feed into set_value - which would be very cool.

In any case, it would be great to get an understanding of what can go into the index/col to be interpreted as indexers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a fair bit of code digging and experimentation it appears that the indexer being looked for by the "takeable=True" option needs to be numpy-style location indicia (e.g. integers, ellipsis, colons, or arrays of boolean or int). So, my main problem was trying to use labels. It won't solve my problems though because it doesn't do expansion (adding rows or columns). For the sake of anyone else wondering what those "takeable" indexes are, here is an example including how it interacts with multi-indexes!

First lets make a multi-index dataframe:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
         np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
df
        0   1   2   3
bar one 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
bar two 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
baz one 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
baz two 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
foo one 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
foo two 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
qux one 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
qux two 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

We can quite predictably set a few to 5 by label:

```
 df.set_value((['bar','foo'],['one','two']),3,5)
    df
            0   1   2   3
bar one 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0
bar two 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0
baz one 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
baz two 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
foo one 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0
foo two 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0
qux one 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
qux two 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Setting using a takeable requires the types above, so here I'll provide INTEGER index values. The possibly confusing thing about takeables and multi-indexes is that they use the internal numbering that pandas uses for the multi-index (so for example may be different before and after a sort). It gets pretty complex to figure out what will change with a multi-index and takable. In this case I've used a single column and sorted nicely so the result is somewhat intuitive if you count down the column:

```
df.set_value([1,2,3],2,-1,takeable=True)
df
        0   1   2   3
bar one 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0
bar two 0.0 0.0 -1.0    5.0
baz one 0.0 0.0 -1.0    0.0
baz two 0.0 0.0 -1.0    0.0
foo one 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0
foo two 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0
qux one 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
qux two 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Neither the labels nor the "takeable" approach set appear to set with expansion at this level, however. So it looks like I'll need to set up my new columns the old fashioned way :)

As a mnemonic I now think of "takeable" meaning that you're passing in an index reference that can be "taken" all the way to the numpy input brackets :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `set_value` may be somewhat of a left-over method?  I think the way to do what you're saying is:

```
df.loc[complicated_indexer, complicated_column] = 0
df.iloc[complicated_indexer, complicated_column] = 0
```

Depending on if your indexers are positions (`iloc`) or labels (`loc`).

Comment: Well, I tried that first and wasn't able to set complex areas in a multiindex with expansion, is it your impression that should work? From what I've read the key will be finding how to pass the correct mask I'm trying to work with into the iterator at the heart of pandas/numpy. I will try more with .loc in the morning if nobody else has other suggestions.

Comment: It would help if you show an example of what you mean by complex indexer or what you want to accomplish.  Many MultiIndex queries can be expressed through [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/advanced.html#using-slicers)

Comment: Yes, you're right of course. My apologies that I've stepped away from the computer for a family night - I guess I was thinking I had missed something obvious and someone would just point me at an explanation of how to use the indexers. I will concoct a minimum viable example in the morning if no magic has occurred, my apologies again.

Comment: No problem! I honestly don't think I had seen `set_value` before.

Comment: Hi chrisb. Once I was working on the minimal example with a fresh morning ahead of me I just went ahead and experimented and dug into the pandas code and figured out what takeable means and why it won't do expansion, see above. Using .loc fails silently at expansion too, try df.loc[idx[['bar','foo'],['one','two','three']],idx[2]]=4 on the matrix I gave above and it will silently NOT add row 'three' to 'bar' and 'foo'. I have a pretty complex scenario and was hoping to find something with automatic row-column additions (which set_value does for single value inserts!)